# Overlaid raster gets shifted around when printing to pdf or when resizing graphics device with mouse

Tags: raster, r, pdf, graphics

I've spent the past couple of days learning how to use the `maps`, `raster`, and `rgdal` packages to create nice images, but I'm running into trouble when trying to make pdf's for actually presenting.  I'm overlaying two rasters -- one has my data and the other is a mask.  The problem is that the mask moves around depending on the size of the output pdf, AND also with simple resizings of the graphcis device.

I've made a little minimal example here:

```
library(raster)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(rgdal)
lat = seq(from=36,to=40,by = .01)
lon = seq(from=-121,to=-117,by = .01)
d = expand.grid(lon,lat)
colnames(d) = c('lon','lat')
d$z = sin(d$lat)-cos(d$lon)+rnorm(nrow(d))
head(d)
coordinates(d)=~lon+lat
gridded(d)= TRUE
r = raster(d)
dd = expand.grid(lon[lon<120],lat[lat<37])
colnames(dd) = c('lon','lat')
dd$z = 1
coordinates(dd)=~lon+lat
gridded(dd)= TRUE
rr = raster(dd)
map('usa',xlim=c(-123,-116),ylim=c(35,41))
plot(r,add=TRUE)
plot(rr,add=TRUE,col="black",legend = F)
dev.copy2pdf(file = "example.pdf",height=8,width=8)
```

Here is the output when first rendered on my screen:
[image]

And here is the output when I resize the window!
[image]

and the example PDF is different again!  (Unfortunately SE doesn't seem to support pdf images, but if you run the code you can see it on your own machine)

Any idea how to work around this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome the shifting problem you should use image() instead of plot()

```
map('usa',xlim=c(-123,-116),ylim=c(35,41))
image(r,add=TRUE)
image(rr,add=TRUE,col="black",legend = F)
dev.copy2pdf(file = "example.pdf",height=8,width=8)
```